# Traer información del modelo solo con los parámetros que si existen nodejs mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy recibiendo información de un form (marca y modelo de autos), y quiero hacer una consulta con mongoose al modelo, si el usuario selecciona la marca y el modelo, puedo hacer la consulta normalmente, y me trae los autos correspondientes a esa marca y a ese modelo que especificó el usuario, pero si el usuario no coloca el modelo me gustaría que me trajera todos los autos correspondientes a la marca solamente, he tratado de colocarle null a model pero no me trae nada.

Como podría hacer la consulta solo con los parámetros que si existan?

Gracias por la ayuda

```
ctrl.filters = async(req, res)=>{
        const brand = req.params.brand;
        const model = req.params.model;
    
        var cars_by_brand = await productInfo.find({'brand': new RegExp(brand),  'model': new RegExp(model)}).populate('image');
        res.send(cars_by_brand);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma en la que puedes lograr lo que te propones es creando un objeto llamado `query` al cual vas a añadir los campos según si los mismos existen o no en el objeto de parámetros recibido en tu solicitud.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let query = {};

if (req.params.brand) { // preguntamos si existe brands
  query['brand'] = new RegExp(req.params.brand);
}

if (req.params.model) { // preguntamos si existe model
  query['model'] = new RegExp(req.params.model);
}
```

De esta forma tu objeto `query` contendrá sólo las claves que estén incluidas en tu objeto `params`.

El código completo de la implementación para tu caso de uso sería algo así:

```js
ctrl.filters = async(req, res)=>{
  let query = {};
  
  if (req.params.brand) { // preguntamos si existe brands
    query['brand'] = new RegExp(req.params.brand);
  }
  
  if (req.params.model) { // preguntamos si existe model
    query['model'] = new RegExp(req.params.model);
  }
  // siempre que se trabaja con Promesas se debe usar
  // un bloque try / catch
  try {
    let cars_by_brand = await productInfo.find(query).populate('image');
     return res.send(cars_by_brand);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Ocurrió un error en la consulta'
    });
  }
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.